# How to convert given date and time into est zone time in php

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I need to display a date and time in gmt format into est timezone time for ex my given time is

```
12:14 PM Thursday, 10 December 2015
```

and the Est time that want display is

```
1:44 AM Thursday, 10 December 2015
```

I used this code

```
date_default_timezone_set('EST'); 
echo date('m/d/Y g:i a', strtotime($row['date_time']));
```

Comment: Do you *actually* mean EST (which is always UTC-5), or do you mean Eastern Time (which is UTC-5 in winter, and UTC-4 in summer)? It's important to understand the difference. Next, what happens with the code you've already got? Am I right in thinking your server is in the Indian time zone?

Comment: Additionally, when you say a "given" date and time - are you expecting that date and time to be in the Indian time zone, or some other time zone?

Comment: @JonSkeet you right i am using indian time zone, now i want to display time in EST zone only.

Comment: When executing above code it displays given time only. It doesn't convert time into EST zone

Comment: Again, do you mean EST or Eastern Time? And again, what time zone is the value from your row in? Where are you getting it from?

Comment: there is no timezone that PHP recognizes for Eastern standard time.use utc

Comment: @JonSkeet Can you specify which time zone is used on NY, Now the date time value in IST

Comment: The New York time zone is "America/New_York" - that's one example of Eastern Time.

Comment: It seems like this should really just be a matter of parsing, changing time zone, then formatting again. Voting to close as a duplicate of a time zone conversion question.

Comment: I tried this code, working fine now. Thanks for your effort.            $datetime = new DateTime($row['date_time']);
               $ny_time_zone = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
               $datetime->setTimezone($ny_time_zone);
               echo $datetime->format('m/d/Y g:i a');